# Объясните RxJava2. Disposable

Tags: android, android-studio, rxjava, retrofit2, rxjava2

Пишу android приложение. Начал использовать RxJava2 и RxAndroid2. Но во многих вещах еще нет четкого понимания.

Реализовал обращение к API через Retrofit2 которое возвращает `Observable<List<Market>>`

Потом следующий код и предупреждение IDE:

[image: ide screen]

Через `ctrl + space` увидел, что `.subscribe()` возвращает `Disposable`.

Что за Disposable такой? Какая его задача и как его правильно использовать?

По RxJava много статей, простые или самые важные вещи объясняются довольно понятно.

Цитата со статьи (habr.com) [Исследуем RxJava 2 для Android](https://habr.com/company/badoo/blog/328434/)

> Применительно к Observable тип Disposable позволяет вызывать метод dispose, означающий «Я закончил работать с этим ресурсом, мне больше не нужны данные». Если у вас есть сетевой запрос, то он может быть отменён. Если вы прослушивали бесконечный поток нажатий кнопок, то это будет означать, что вы больше не хотите получать эти события, в таком случае можно удалить OnClickListener у View.

Кто реализует интрефейс Disposable? Нужно ли мне беспокоится о том, что написано в цитате при использовании Retrofit? И если я сохраню ссылку на Disposable что полезного потом можно с ней сделать?

Просто от не знания, меня напрягает аннотация `@SuppressLint("CheckResult")` в android проекте, что бы в глаза не бросалось выделение.

Ну и самый главный вопрос: можно/нужно это игнорировать? Или нужно переписать/дописать код с умом.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в rxjava2 `Disposable` появился на замену `unsubscribe()`. Теперь, чтобы отписаться нужно использовать метод `dispose()` на экземпляре этого класса. Игнорить его можно, но тогда потеряете возможность отписаться. Одна из реализаций 
- `CompositeDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Так вы (и GC) точно знаете, что есть поток данных от источника к вам.
2. `Disposable` лучше сохранить в поле и отписываться при потере `Context`, если код его использует. Отписываться полезно чтобы избежать утечек памяти и бесполезной работы.

Интерфейс `Disposable` реализуют часто как место с ссылкой на собственно поток данных, иногда даже анонимкой; некоторые observable могут прекращать генерировать данные при отсутствии подписчиков.

CheckResult тут не просто так, потеря ссылки на `Disposable`/`Subscription` может привести не неочевидным последствиям (и не даст возможности отписаться).